# how to Send Bulk Mail using Amazon webservices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to send mass mails using Amazon SES web services. However, I'm not getting such reference in .NET. Can anyone help me?

Comment: suggest looking at:
http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkfornet/

Comment: i'm looking for the code in .net

Comment: http://www.neuralab.net/development-software-coding/amazon-ses-simple-email-service-c-code-examples-asp-net-codes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig amConfig = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig();
amConfig.UseSecureStringForAwsSecretKey = false;
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient amzClient = new    
    AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AKID"].ToString(),     
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Secret"].ToString(), amConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SendEmailRequest ser = new SendEmailRequest("VERIFIED_EMAIL_HERE", dest, message);
SendEmailResponse seResponse = amzClient.SendEmail(ser);
SendEmailResult seResult = seResponse.SendEmailResult;
```

(Text included to get past minimum non-space requirements of SO)